# Are there floating point infinitesimals?

Tags: c, floating-point

Since there are finitely many floating point numbers and one can compare each possible pair of such numbers (I assume), there must always exist a number 'b' which is

1. smaller than some given number 'a' (not +/- infinity) and
2. there exists no number 'c' smaller than 'a' and greater than 'b';

i.e. the 'next' smaller floating-point-represented number. I wonder if:

1. there is a function smaller(float a) returning such number b (or greater(float a) for that matter) in the C programming language
2. if not, then if there is a way to obtain these 'next' numbers for certain types of numbers 'a', for example if 'a' is an integer/zero.

Trying

```
float smaller(float a) return a - 0.00...001f;
```

seems to me like a hack that probably doesn't work for all possible inputs, but I might be wrong, so that's why I'm turning to you guys. Any help is appretiated.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Also take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is. You're after the "nextafter" family of functions.

These can be used to move from one floating point number to the next, much in the same way as you can use `++` and `--` for integral types.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter

(This is C documentation).

Comment: I had no idea these functions existed.  Good to know!

Comment: damn, probably should've shaped my google queries differently. tyvm ;)

Answer (score 6):

[The C99/POSIX functions `nextafter`/`nexttoward`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nextafter.3.html) can do this. You provide a start value `x` and a destination value `y`, and they return the next value from the start in the direction of the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your language does not have the `nextafter` family of functions, but does let you treat values stored in memory as integers (by pointer casting or other, dirtier tricks), then, for any floating-point type (`double`, `float`, `half`, ...) that conforms to IEEE 754, if you want to find the next **larger** number than `value`, you can do

```
FLOATING value = ...;

if (value >= 0) {
    integer_increment(value);
} else {
    integer_decrement(value);
}
```

and vice versa for the next **smaller** number, where `integer_increment` increments the value of `value` as if `value` was of an integral type.

Comment: does that really work for all numbers? Not saying that it doesn't, but with all the stuff that's going on (such as NaNs, denormals, infinities, biased exponent) I find this really surprising

Comment: @julaine Yes, IEEE 754 is truly beautiful. The main trick is the fact that the mantissa can attain values from 1.0 to 1.9999..., which means that even the largest "jump" in value you can cause by adjusting mantissa, is always smaller than 2. On the other hand, the exponential part is 2^exponent, and the exponent can change only by integer amounts (i.e. by 1 at most), so the smallest "jump" in value you can cause by adjusting the exponent, is 2. And now take a look how the parts of the float are ordered! First, you have the sign, then you have the exponent part, and lastly the mantissa.

Comment: @julaine Hence, the exponent part bits are all more significant bits than the mantissa bits. That means when taking the individual bits of the float and incrementing the number as if it was an integer, you first increment the mantissa from 1.0 to 1.99999 up until the very edge of 1.9999, and then you zero it and carry the last bit over to the exponent, which is then increased by 1 and the number as a whole is multiplied by 2 instead of by 1.9999.

Comment: @julaine You can basically think of the exponent part as splitting the entire numberline into buckets (of uneven sizes!) and the mantissa as interpolating the exact value within each bucket. This works even for +- infinity, as adding 1 bit to the bit representation of the largest non-infinite float results in +inf, and vice versa for -inf (only difference is sign bit). Same thing for denormalized numbers - we basically declare that if exp part is 0, then we treat mantissa not as 1.0 - 1.9999, but 0.0 - 0.9999, and the real exponent stays as -126, so the numbers are again perfectly ordered

Comment: @julaine It probably doesn't make sense to say that the "next" number after +-inf is NaN (which is true in the binary representation), but that's the only exception I can think of other than the order changes around zero (see code). The IEEE 754 float is basically sign + absolute part, and the absolute part is well-ordered, just like integers. It was a smart design choice :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was insightful. I wonder why they did that - "incrementing" floats is not really a common thing, and comparing two floats is still not optimizable as an integer-operation because NaN-handling is required. Or maybe it's more of an unintentional lucky consequence of the design rather than a deliberate choice?

Comment: @julaine I would say that NaN handling is often times not required, and even if it was, you can just preprocess your data and throw out NaNs. I got into this topic myself from an old school assignment - find exactly a given percentile among a ~20GB array of floats using 200kB memory. Thanks to the fact that floats are well-ordered, you can bucket them by bits instead of by "value", and when you can calculate bucket index by bit shifting, woo wee, the algorithm is very fast.

Comment: @julaine You can also secretly adapt all sorting algos that work on "integers" to work on your floats now, such as radix sort, which can get extremely fast when you know that your floats are in a specific range, from which you determine the most significant exponent bit and wave goodbey to boring O(nlogn) sorts

Comment: @julaine But originally, you basically need the CPU to be able to answer the question "is a > b" for floats as fast as possible. Hence they need to be easily comparable, just like integers - find the first most significant bit difference (+ account for sign bit)